# Which key is being pressed on event text wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wx.textctrl

I'm using wx.TextCrtl bind to wx.EVT_TEXT for receiving input from the user but I don't know how to detect which key has been pressed (I can read the last char on the string using st[LengthOfString-1] but it's not good for keys that are not letters (backspace key for example). If I use the wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN event, then I can't see the data inserted.
What can I do to have them both? text control with an option to manipulate the string and also the option to detect each key upon pressing?

```
self.command_line = wx.TextCtrl(self.CommandLinePanel, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)  # past: self.log.
        self.command_line.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnKeyCommandLine)

def OnKeyCommandLine(self, event):
    st = str(event.GetString())
    LengthOfSt = len(st)
    #...
    #my code
    #End of function
```

How can I add something like

```
self.command_line.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyWhich)

def OnKeyWhich(self, evt):
    print "The key pressed: %s" % evt.GetKeyCode()
```

and receive the two events or at least the outcomes from the two events?

Comment: Solved: I used event.Skip() at the end of OnKeyWhich function.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help:

```
# Define an event handler
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.OnKeyWhich, self.command_line)

# Determine when user push RETURN (for example):
def OnKeyWhich(self, event): 
    key = event.GetKeyCode()                
    if key == wx.WXK_RETURN:
        self.update_result()
    else:
        event.Skip()
```

Here is a list of Keycodes:
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.KeyCode.enumeration.html

Good look!